# (React hook form) useForm, shouldFocusError: false not working

Tags: react-hooks, react-hook-form, chakra-ui

I am using React hook form like so:

```
  const form = useForm({
    mode: 'onSubmit',
    shouldUnregister: true,
    reValidateMode: 'onBlur',
    shouldFocusError: false,
  });
```

[image]

I am manually overriding the error validation message focus because I have a custom error summary above the first field in the form. I trying to scroll to that custom error summary div:

```
    <Box
      p='c.4'
      border='2px'
      borderColor='red.500'
      data-testid='errors-block'
      role='group'
      aria-live='polite'
      data-invalid
      aria-labelledby='errorSummaryHeading'
    >
      <Stack spacing='c.4'>
        <Heading id={errorSummaryHeadingId} as='h3' size='h4'>
          Something went wrong
        </Heading>
      </Stack>
    </Box>
```

Even with the `shouldFocusError: false`, the focus is still being set to the first field with validation errors.

Here is the code I am using to scroll when submitting the form:

```
document.body.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
```

What's interesting is, when the form submit button is clicked a second time the error summary is scrolled to correctly. I believe this is because the react hook form errors are already visible. This suggests the `shouldFocusError: false` is not working.

Are there any gotchas that I need to be aware of that may be stopping me from implementing this focus override functionality?

I have tried using the documentation on react hook form.

I expect setting `shouldFocusError: false` on the `useForm` invocation should disable scrolling/focus on the first form validation error.

The actual result is equivalent to `shouldFocusError: true`.